# How to set up a spark standalone cluster with docker to execute python jobs from external containers?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to configure a spark standalone cluster using the following docker-compose.yaml file:

```yaml
spark:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.3.2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
      - '7077:7077'
spark-worker:
  image: bitnami/spark:3.3.2
  environment:
    - SPARK_MODE=worker
    - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark:7077
    - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=4G
    - SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=4G
    - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=4
  ports:
    - '8082:8081'
```

The idea is to keep cluster up on a physical machine (with the master and the worker) ready to receive python job submissions coming from containers in other machines.

For example:

- The machine A is hosting the cluster (spark+worker), created using `docker-compose up`
- In machine B, I will create a spark container to run python job using spark-submit --master spark://:7077
- In the machine C, I have a Airflow worker container also trying to run a python job using spark-submit
- A jupyter notebook container creates a spark session to perform interactive computations.

I have successfully set up my Spark cluster on a physical machine. The master node is able to properly identify the worker nodes, and jobs submitted within the cluster (from both the master and worker nodes) run smoothly.

However, I encountered an issue when attempting to submit a job from a container running in other machine. While the job appears in the master's UI, it becomes stuck in an infinite loop with executors being requested, created, and destroyed repeatedly.

```
23/04/16 22:06:39 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 9 requested
23/04/16 22:06:39 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
23/04/16 22:06:39 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 9 from BlockManagerMaster.
23/04/16 22:06:39 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20230416220604-0001/11 on hostPort 10.18.0.130:45783 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
23/04/16 22:06:39 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20230416220604-0001/11 is now RUNNING
23/04/16 22:06:45 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20230416220604-0001/10 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
23/04/16 22:06:45 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20230416220604-0001/10 removed: Command exited with code 1
23/04/16 22:06:45 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20230416220604-0001/12 on worker-20230416220203-10.18.0.73-36107 (10.18.0.73:36107) with 1 core(s)
23/04/16 22:06:45 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20230416220604-0001/12 on hostPort 10.18.0.73:36107 with 1 core(s), 1024.0 MiB RAM
23/04/16 22:06:45 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 10 requested
23/04/16 22:06:45 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 10 from BlockManagerMaster.
```

I believe that the problem is likely caused by incorrect networking configurations, as the executors may not have been able to communicate properly with the driver. However, I'm uncertain about how to resolve the issue.

I attempted to expose ports 10001 to 10005 in both the container that submits the application and the Spark worker, using them as the values for `spark.driver.port`, `spark.blockManager.port`, and `spark.driver.blockManager.port`.

Additionally, I tried configuring `spark.driver.host` with the IP address of the machine that runs the container submitting the job (using spark-submit). However, this resulted in the following error:

```
23/04/27 17:47:10 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'sparkDriver' failed after 16 retries (starting from 10003)!
```

I had also made the above tests running the cluster (created using docker compose up) and the container that executes the spark submit (using docker run bitnami/spark) on the same machine, setting `spark.driver.host` to the ip of that machine (obtained via hostname -I), but the errors persists.

My question is - how to configure the cluster and/or the individual containers to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you configure your jobs? Do you have enough resources to start executor on the machine?

Comment: I conducted the tests using the `pi.py` example available in the Spark image. The worker was configured with 4GB of RAM and 4 CPUs. In fact, when I ran the same spark-submit command from within the cluster, the job executed smoothly.